# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException error on MySQL JDBC java project

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, lamp

I'm new to ubuntu, and in the last days I installed eclipse and lamp for working with a project that was already running on windows7. The problem is that the same string of connection doesn't works. Here is the piece of code in witch I try to connect:

```
    String stringaConn = null;
        String nomeClasse = null;
        stringaConn = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cinemapreverificasql?user=root";
        nomeClasse = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(nomeClasse);
            System.out.println("forName eseguito");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Classe nomeClasse - Driver non trovata");
        }
        try {
            f.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(stringaConn);
            System.out.println("Aperta la connessione");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Stringa di connessione errata");
        }
```

It enters in the second catch and prints the string "Stringa di connessione errata". Here is an example of output:

```
forName eseguito
Stringa di connessione errata
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gestioneDegliEventi.Gestione.windowOpened(Gestione.java:199)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2048)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:296)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2009)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Searching on internet I tried the solution of changing the connection string in:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cinemapreverificasql?user=root
```

and give the permission with `sudo ufw allow 3306`, but the error risen is the same. What could be the error?

Comment: Well what's line 199? And where are you initializing `f`?

Comment: at line 199 there is `stmSql = f.conn.prepareStatement("select * from film");` , and there is the error cause `f.conn` is null. `f` is initialized in the constructor, and `conn` is public in `f` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so now that you've shown the line that's actually blowing up:

```
stmSql = f.conn.prepareStatement("select * from film");
```

And `f.conn` is null. That's because when you assign a value to `f.conn`, if anything goes wrong you print out an error message and then keep going as if nothing had happened:

```
try {
    f.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(stringaConn);
    System.out.println("Aperta la connessione");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Stringa di connessione errata");
}
```

**Don't do that.** Don't catch the exception here. You're really not *handling* it properly, in that after the catch statement your object is *not* ready to be used. You're also swallowing the exception without displaying any of the information in it, which makes it even hard to work out what's *really* wrong.

The method you've shown should probably just declare that it can throw `SQLException`, and then not try to catch anything. That way, if something goes wrong you stop immediately rather than continuing when you're bound to fail.

When you log the exception wherever you actually log it, log the *whole* exception - not just a message saying that something's wrong. It's entirely possible that the exception information will tell you exactly what's wrong with your connection string.

Oh, and you probably shouldn't be doing any of this in the UI thread, either - but that's a very separate issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice. The problem was just a matter of permission, root user had a password that on win there wasn't.